# Returning user profile properties on a page layout in SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint, user-controls, office365

On my SharePoint 2013 dev environment this code in a custom page layout brings back the current users first name:

```
<SPSWC:ProfilePropertyValue runat="server" TitleMode="true" PropertyName="FirstName"/>
```

However if I add this to a page layout in SharePoint Online in Office 365 it returns nothing (just blank).

Is this a possible bug or by design?

I want to bring back this property server side rather than with client side scripts as I want to be able to use it before doc ready.

Answer (score 1):

I discovered the answer was because you need to use the 'ProfilePropertyLoader' tag first eg: